# different datasource to single material table in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, angular-material-stepper

I want to display data in angular material table by based on submit button of selected stepper tab.I want to pass dynamic parameters to each stepper tab submit button. The datasource needs to be changed accordingly passed parameters and the table also.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am beginner in angular.